# How to extract certain links and write to text file

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm newbie in C# and specially in Selenium. The code I'm providing works as intended, but I would like to add to it. Basically how to use Selenium to log into Linkedin, search for CURRENT EMPLOYEES of a company (Walmart for this example) and scrape the links for "send inmail" for every user.... clicking the "next" button on every page until there are no more. The following will open linkedin, login, enter walmart into searchbox, then click the next button.

I would like to write the links found within all the Send InMail buttons to a text file. Inspecting one of the Send InMail buttons gives the following:

```html
 <a class="primary-action-button label" href="/requestList?displayProposal=&amp;destID=262919732&amp;creationType=DC&amp;authToken=BrmS&amp;authType=name&amp;trk=vsrp_people_res_pri_act&* amp;trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A5225861601486589992400%2CVSRPtargetId%3A262919732%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary">Send InMail</a>
```

I would like to write all of these links into a text file as it cycles through all the "next" buttons. Also, I would like to know how to select a value from a drop down list that I haven't been able to "inspect" ... When you type "Walmart" or whatever into the search box, a drop-down gives you the option of selecting "people that currently work at walmart", etc. I haven't even been able to inspect that option in developer mode for some reason.
I've updated my code... This now SEEMS to WANT to do what i need...but there seems to be a timing issue where the "next" button might be loading before the "Send InMail" buttons...it will print a few results to the console and clicks next a few times, but then seems to melt down:

```
// Go to the home page
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.linkedin.com");



            // Get User Name field, Password field and Login Button
            var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("login-email");
            var userPasswordField = driver.FindElementById("login-password");
            var loginButton = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='Sign in']");

            // Type user name and password
            userNameField.SendKeys("me@hotmail.com");
            userPasswordField.SendKeys("Password123");

            // and click the login button
            loginButton.Click();

            // perform search
            var newSearch = driver.FindElementById("main-search-box");
            var searchButton = driver.FindElementByName("search");

            // search
            newSearch.SendKeys("walmart");
            searchButton.Click();

            // Get all links from Send InMail buttons
            List<IWebElement> elementList = new List<IWebElement>();
            elementList.AddRange(driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Next >")));
            if (elementList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(IWebElement item in driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Send InMail")))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(item.GetAttribute("href"));
                    var goForward = driver.FindElementByLinkText("Next >");
                    goForward.Click();

                }
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, after you perform search, there will be a search results which will be populated in the list like the ones in the figure attached.

[screenshot of the Linkedin search result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i1Bb.png)

Then iterate through the results using similar method (code sample here is in Java, might be similar in C#)

```
List<WebElements> results_div = driver.findElemnts(By.xpath("//*[@id="results"]")) // where xpath of the <ul> element

int counter = 2 // because the data starts from id = 2. Refer image.
while(counter <= results_div)
{
     WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-li-position=\"+counter+\"])) //xpath of the <li> element
     String anchor_text = element.findElement(By.linkText("Send InMail")).getAtribute("href")

    //Write a logic to save the data to a text file 
}
```

Iterate the above until all the results are reached!

Hope it helps.

Edit : Try this, its not a working code! But try it on these grounds. It might help.

```
@Test(description = "Search the Site with some predefined words after Login and print the href attribute")
public void printUserID()
{
    StartPage startPage = new StartPage(driver);
    HomePage homePage = startPage.loginIntoAccount(LinkdinAccount.linkedEmail,LinkdinAccount.linkedPassword); // Logs in in to the account

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-search-box\"]")).sendKeys("herbalife");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"global-search\"]/fieldset/button")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"results\"]"))));

    List<WebElement> results_div = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"results\"]/li")); // where xpath of the <ul> element
    System.out.println(results_div.size()); //*[@id="results"]

    #driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"results-pagination\"]/ul/li[11]/a")).click();

    int count = 1;

         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"results\"]"))));

    while(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"results-pagination\"]/ul/li[11]/a")).isDisplayed())
    {
       while(count <= results_div.size())
       { 
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-li-position=\"" + count + "\"]"));


        if(element.findElements(By.linkText("Send Inmail")).size() > 0)
        {
            String anchor_text = element.findElement(By.linkText("Send InMail")).getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(anchor_text);
        }

        count ++;
        }
    //for clicking the next button 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"results-pagination\"]/ul/li[11]/a")).click()
    }
```

Comment: I would like to do this in C# using selenium, just as a learning exercise. I want to print out the links associated with the "Send InMail" buttons. When I try the following:                                                                       `var mailLinks = driver.FindElementsByLinkText("Send InMail");` and
`Console.WriteLine(mailLinks);`, it doesn't return the href link I'm wanting, instead, it writes this to console: _System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]_

Comment: OK...I used the .getAttribute("href") from your suggestion (with 2 t's) and that does make it print the actual link.

Comment: I would just like to know how to print out all of the links using only C# with selenium

Comment: Not yet....I have gotten a little farther thanks to your advice on ".getAttribute("href")" ...and have created a loop to print those links to console then click the next button if present, but it only prints the links from one page, then clicks the next button a few times before stopping in debug mode...thinking it is some kind of timing issue?